# Pass complex numbers to and from a DLL in LabVIEW

Tags: c++, dll, labview

I am trying to interface [this C++ code](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Faddeeva_Package) -- which implements functions necessary to calculate a Voigt line shape -- with LabVIEW (I'm currently running LV2009). I successfully compiled the code into a DLL, and I set up the `Call Library Function Node` to point to the DLL. However, the function expects a vector of type complex double and returns a vector of type complex double. Complex double is not, however, one of my choices for data type when setting up the function prototype.

Unfortunately, I do not speak C/C++, so I don't have any idea how I would go about modifying the code to get and return real doubles only. I have compiled the code into a MEX file to use with MATLAB, and pass complex numbers in and out with no problem, so I know the code works.

Is there a way to trick LabVIEW 2009 into passing complex numbers in and out of DLL functions? If not, will I gain this ability if I upgrade to the newest release? If not, is there a good basic guide to C++ that will teach me how to modify the function to accept and return the real and imaginary parts as separate vectors?

Answer (score 2):

LabVIEW doesn't allow interfacing with C++ code, only C (or if it's C++, it has to have the `extern "C"` declaration and use Plain Old Types).

I see that your library has C wrappers, but they use the new C99 `complex` type, which LabVIEW doesn't understand.

However LabVIEW can pass complex data type to a function, to see how it's done open the example named "Call DLL.vi" and select complex data-type to see function prototype and VI. Your chance might be that the C99 `complex` has the same binary representation than the LabVIEW one. I didn't dig for the info, but it might be very possible.

If it's the case, go to church and be grateful to your Lord, and use the C wrapper to interface to it.

If it's not, find a tutorial about making a DLL for your compiler, it's not difficult, just takes time. The DLL will take two `double` for each complex, and make the appropriate call to the real function.

Comment: Great answer.  I've written a ton of C/C++ FFT code that gets called in Labview and wrappers are the way to go when messing around with complex numbers.